# Cuadro alrededor al dar click a elemento HTML

Tags: html, css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Existe alguna forma de quitar cuadro alrededor el elemento que sale al darle click?

Comment: Procura siempre proveer un [mcve], de otro modo tu pregunta no se ajusta a [ask] y por ende quedaría cerrada

Comment: Isaac, es buena práctica desde el punto de vista de accesibilidad, dar siempre al usuario indicaciones de que se ha seleccionado un elemento. En ese sentido, quitar el `outiline` tal y como sugiere la respuesta de @anythingg funcionaría pero no sería apropiado a menos que lo sustituyas por otra indicación clara hacia el usuario (algunos navegan con teclado).

Comment: @Sokkian En este caso funciona como un <a>, el detalle es que estoy usando react y como la pagina no recarga se queda con este outline. Pero creo que en ese caso un **cursor: pointer** funcionaria para indicar que es un elemento clickeable.

Comment: Si utilizas el teclado para moverte entre enlaces (que es un caso más habitual de lo que se puede imaginar), un cursor: pointer no es un indicador, ya que solo sabes que el enlace está seleccionado si está en estado :focus. Si se trata de una app para movil entonces da igual porque no se puede usar el teclado como mecanismo de navegación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eliminar para un link

```
a{outline:none;}
```

Eliminar para imágenes dentro  de un link

```
a img {outline : none;}
```

Eliminar para imágenes

```
img {border : 0;}
```

Comment: Nota: hacer `outline: none` crea problemas de accesibilidad web y no debería hacerse si no se proporciona un servicio equivalente al usuario para identificar dónde se encuentra.